# Using git with ssh for Phabricator

Tags: git, ssh, phabricator

I'm configure my server to run ssh with Phabricator config for using git with ssh.
But when I'm trying to connect to server through ssh I gets next thing in my sshd log

```
debug3: Running AuthorizedKeysCommand: "/usr/libexec/phabricator-ssh-hook.sh vcs-user" as "vcs-user"
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'command="'/srv/www/phabricator/phabricator/bin/ssh-exec''
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug2: user_key_allowed: check options: 'command="'/srv/www/phabricator/phabricator/bin/ssh-exec' '--phabricator-ssh-user' 'bogdaniy' '--phabricator-ssh-key' '1'",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB1NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC9Vw/7rVzgEhk9W+zdFZ8Qsb/6ZBdjnGouhzqkPrXGiD6apbtS3tarSwXYjuqZxJMGJmkO0PcSUx1YBzpIvlYM6OJ2etzj7+P0wi573C6pDXxb+fJtPGOQJDnhN/v/9HaCLVOL5tvMmFhVWMH25bgCKGtqrZtpgnkReBEWfqTW1zux9c0O783DfHU1yIsc+epRNSKh0HUcDRZISZ3jMDMF8LZs4VBFJFYiADKI8u17HdOcopx98DpRsnDi8t6kj11nh/GzXyxBlTT1CGv8APCHeJRzW8uWspj88TGL4j50J42sEQjM4EzImnkKTvoGyiWYMBGazLt+vN/2guRM4Ost
'
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type 'Ssh-rsa'
```

I see that in [good log](https://secure.phabricator.com/P1211) after ssh-exec peoples get something like

```
debug1: matching key found: file /etc/phabricator-ssh-hook.sh, line 1 RSA 6a:e7:4c:68:96:7e:4c:87:3c:2f:ca:cd:8d:3e:34:5a
```

Answer (score 0):

This would tend to indicate an issue with the format of your public key. Was it generated from Phabricator (in the UI) or is it one you imported?

Also, you can have a look at the guide from Bitnami:
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Phabricator#Using_SSH_authentication